# What music was used in "Glenn The Flying Robot"?

Tags: music-identification, glenn-the-flying-robot

I am aware that it is a passage of Bach but does anyone know the title of the piece? It is played throughout the film but mainly near the end where both the main pianist rivals need to play it together.

I am also curious about the title of the song played when Jack (the main character with the broken hand) is outside, smoking. I believe it has an acoustic guitar (forgive me if I'm wrong) playing in the background whilst the singer performs his song.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The piano piece seems to be the *Prelude and Fugue in C minor (BWV 847)*, indeed by Bach